# The type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I know that this question has been already asked, but I cannot find anything that can help solve my problem.

I want to connect my `aspx` page (`Retete.aspx`) to a Microsoft SQL database. I'm getting this error on `Retete.aspx.cs`:

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'GlobalClass' does not exist in the namespace 'ProiectSera' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>   The error points to this line of code:

```
ProiectSera.GlobalClass.Update(ValRefTempSol.Text, ValRefTempAer.Text);
```

Where `ProiectSera` is the project name, `GlobalClass` is the file where I make the operation on the db.

My using statements are:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using ProiectSera;
```

The Target Framework is set to [.net-4.5](/questions/tagged/.net-4.5).

What should I do to solve this error?

**Update**
My GlobalClass.cs is:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using ProiectSera;

using System.Data.Services;

namespace ProiectSera.App_Code
{
    public static class GlobalClass
    {
        static public void Update(string _param1, string _param2)
        {//function to update}
}
}
```

App_Code is a folder where GlobalClass.cs is. I tried and

```
ProiectSera.App_Code.GlobalClass.Update(ValRefTempSol.Text, ValRefTempAer.Text); //
```

but I had the same error. And I put the GlobalClass.cs in the project's root. I also removed the *.App_Code* from `namespace ProiectSera.App_Code`

**UPDATE1**
My Retete.aspx.cs is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using ProiectSera;
using ProiectSera.App_Code;

namespace ProiectSera
{
    public partial class Retete : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string intValRefTempSol;
            string intValRefTempAer;

 //           intValRefTempSol = ValRefTempSol.Text;
 //           intValRefTempAer = ValRefTempAer.Text;


   //         ProiectSera.App_Code.GlobalClass.Update(ValRefTempSol.Text, ValRefTempAer.Text);
            GlobalClass.Update(ValRefTempSol.Text, ValRefTempAer.Text);
}
}
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter what is in your "using" statements, what matters is what's in your "Project References".

Comment: is `GlobalClass` file or `class` ? make sure it's `public`

Comment: @BryceWagner what should contain "Project References"?

@ tchelidze is a file, GlobalClass.cs. Is public.

Comment: is GlobalClass in the same project as the Retete.aspx?

Comment: @knightsb yes, it is in the same project.

Comment: Is Update a static method of GlobalClass? Or is GlobalClass static? Also, don't prefix it with ProiectSera (don't know if you really meant ProjectSera or whether this is a language thing?) either. Just GlobalClass.Update(etc, etc) is fine. You're going to need a project reference to ProiectSera from your web application, if this is a separate lib too.

Comment: Are you supposed to be referencing ProiectSera or ProjectSera?

Comment: @ManoDestra it is: static public void Update(string _param1, string _param2) {...}

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre ProiectSera is the name of my VS project.

Comment: Okay, well so long as you have a project reference (if it's in a separate project), and you have `using ProiectSera;` (assuming this isn't a typo), then just use `GlobalClass.Update(param1, param2, etc)`.

Comment: Make also sure the target framework on the **referenced** project is compatible.

Comment: @ManoDestra So. My Retete.aspx.cs file and GlobalClass.cs file are in the same VS project. It's the first time when I do this, so that's why things may be confuse for me.

Comment: @magn can you attach the namespace from your GlobalClass.

Comment: @knightsb what do you mean?

Comment: in the top of your GlobalClass.cs you should declare it's namespace: somthing like namespace MyProject.SomeSpecificNameSpace{
 public class GlobalClass
    {
        
    }
}

Comment: You don't need `using ProiectSera;` inside a class that is already defined in that namespace (in Retete.aspx.cs). Not your problem here, but it's worth getting rid of that to avoid more confusion. Personally, I'd start from scratch and get rid of GlobalClass. Recreate it, by adding a class to the App_Code directory and see what namespace it gives you. Then paste your code from the original GlobalClass into your new one. Then, use that namespace given to refer to it from your other class.

Comment: I'm gonna try it tomorrow 'cause it's late where I am. If I'll have any questions may I bother you? Many thanks for your time!

Comment: If you remove the `using ProiectSera.App_Code;` line from your code and just type GlobalClass somewhere in your code. Then click on that bit of text and hit Ctrl-Alt-F10. It should bring up options to help you bind it. If it comes up with something like Generate class for and no options regarding using statements, then your project has no concept of GlobalClass defined in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `GlobalClass` is in the namespace `ProiectSera.App_Code`.

So the class name is `ProiectSera.App_Code.GlobalClass`

Make sure you don't have a `ProiectSera` class in the `ProiectSera` namespace also, otherwise if declaring `using ProiectSera` on top, it'll try to use it (as a general rule, don't name any class the same as your namespace).

If that still doesn't work, you may want to try using the `global` namespace:

```
global::ProiectSera.GlobalClass.Update(ValRefTempSol.Text, ValRefTempAer.Text);
```

and see if that works: if it doesn't, and `GlobalClass` is in the same project, then there's something else you haven't shown us

**Update**

The only other thing that comes to mind, if you are positive that both files are on the same project/assembly, is that `GlobalClass.cs` is not being actually compiled. Make sure the `Build Action` is set to `Compile` (you can see the build action right clicking on the `GlobalClass.cs` in the solution explorer and selecting `Properties`).

Comment: @magn after your update, if you are 100% positive that `GlobalClass.cs` and `Retete.cs` are in the same project (even on different folders), if `global::ProiectSera.App_Code.GlobalClass.Update(...)` didn't work, the only thing that comes to mind is that your `GlobalClass.cs` is not being compiled. Make sure the `Build Action` on `GlobalClass.cs` is set to `Compile` (right click on the fle in the solution explorer and select `Properties` to see the property window)

Comment: @magn so it was not being compiled?

Comment: Yeah. I didn't set the Build Action to compile. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using VS.NET:

1. Right click on the References folder on your project.
2. Select Add Reference.
3. Select the .NET tab (or select the Browse button if it is not a .NET Framework assembly).
4. Double-click the assembly containing the namespace in the error message.
5. Press the OK button.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the following...

- That you have a project reference to ProiectSera from your web application, if it's in a separate library. If GlobalClass is in the web application project itself, you won't require this, but if GlobalClass is defined in a separate library in the same solution or elsewhere, then you're going to need to [add a reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to that external library in your web application.
- Ensure that ProiectSera should not be ProjectSera (if it's a typo).
- Ensure that you have your ProiectSera using statement in place at the top (`using ProiectSera;`). Assuming that this is the correct namespace. Check the namespace of your GlobalClass class and use that using accordingly in the class that wishes to use its functionality.
- Then, simply call this in your code, assuming that Update is a static method of GlobalClass.

  `GlobalClass.Update(ValRefTempSol.Text, ValRefTempAer.Text);`

EDIT: given that you've now posted your GlobalClass code, you can see that the namespace for this class is `ProiectSera.App_Code`;. So you need to have that as your using statement in the other class `using ProiectSera.App_Code;`. And then call it via simply GlobalClass.Update, as mentioned above.

If you don't understand how namespacing works in C#, then I recommend you check this out (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s.aspx).

Comment: Let me see if I understood well. This error appears when these 2 files are in separate projects?

Comment: It can do, but it may also occur if you're simply not referring to GlobalClass correctly in the same project. And this requires you to have the correct using statement based on the namespace of GlobalClass. And then referring to that class and method correctly (as I've written it above).

Comment: I tried and how you sugested, to remove the project name and to have only: GlobalClass.Update(ValRefTempSol.Text, ValRefTempAer.Text);
But the problem is the same.
I update my question with information.

Comment: I've updated my answer. You're not including the correct namespace for GlobalClass. The namespace is ProiectSera.App_Code. Add that as your using statement and then just call GlobalClass.Update().

Comment: Also, ensure that GlobalClass is in the same PROJECT as your web application. If it's in a separate class library in the same SOLUTION, or elsewhere, then you're going to need a reference to that library in your web application project.

Comment: Retete.aspx.cs is in the project's root. GlobalClass is in App_code folder which is in the SAME project. using ProiectSera.App_Code; should I put in Retete.aspx.cs, no?

Comment: If it's definitely in the same project, then you either call it via `ProiectSera.App_Code.GlobalClass.Update(param1, param2);` OR you including the using statement for the namespace `using ProiectSera.App_Code;` and then you can just use `GlobalClass.Update(param1, param2);` If you just type GlobalClass without the using and then right-click GlobalClass, it should come up with the option of how to insert it, with or without using. If it doesn't come up with any suggestions via intellisense, then GlobalClass is not in that project and you have no reference for it.

Comment: I put in Retete.aspx.cs: using ProiectSera.App_Code; and then `GlobalClass.Update(param1, param2);`
The error I get now is: `The type or namespace name 'App_Code' does not exist in the namespace 'ProiectSera' (are you missing an assembly reference?)` . Is like The App_code folder is not in my project? But it certainly is. What else could I do?

Comment: There's a little box that appears to help you bind missing namespaces, like this (http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_TyfoHDL02pM/SsyzgvIQSYI/AAAAAAAAAbM/QKKbtya0NLA/s400/Shift-Alt-F10.bmp). If you don't get these options appearing when you click this box to help you bind the class, then you are missing a reference to it. Or it does not exist in the current project.

Comment: Intellisense should autocomplete what's available. If you start typing `using Pro`, does it come up with ProiectSera as an option in Intellisense? If so, then check that App_Code comes up after you type `using ProiectSera.`. If it does not, then you have done something wrong in your code. You should have an App_Code folder in there. Check the default namespace of your web project also, in the project settings.

Comment: What reference I am missing? `System.Configuration` is added.

Comment: If GlobalClass is defined in your project, then you don't need a reference to any other library to use it. Only if it's contained in another library do you need to add a reference to it. I think your problem here is incorrect namespacing and usage of those namespaces (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s.aspx).